# I need copied text to be displayed on clicking to button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when i copy some text and when i click on any button or link i wanted to show copied content.  I wanted this to work on all browsers.I tried `window.clipboardata,` working fine in ie browser but i need for chrome. Copied contents i wanted to show on clicking, i dont want it to be displayed by using ctrl+v.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

As per official Google Forum (https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/suwKfZVJqaI), you cannot access clipboard in Google Chrome browser.  The support has been disabled years ago.

Comment: (but you can still copy to it)